# Insert legend using mapped column labels and colors parameter

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, mapping, bar-chart

I am trying to insert a `legend` that displays the mapped colours that references the appropriate column values. Specifically, for the `df` below the `column` bars are mapped using different `colors`. I am trying to display these colors with the value in the `legend`.

So the intended output will display:

```
A = green
B = blue
C = black
```

Here is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Gr1' :    ['Foo','Boo','Bar','Foo','Bur','Foo','Boo','Bar','Boo'],
    'Gr2' :    ['A','B','B','C','A','B','C','C','A'],
    'Value' :    [1,2,4,6,8,20,25,29,30],
})

colors = {'A':'green', 'B':'blue', 'C': 'black'}
df.plot.bar(x='Gr1', y='Value', color = df['Gr2'].map(colors), label = 'Gr2');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to manually create a legend. Automatic legend creation usually requires different datasets set as different sets of objects. Here's a guide to creating [custom matplotlib legends](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html).  Something like this added should work for you:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

legend_elements = [Patch(facecolor=c, label=x) for x, c in colors.items()]
ax.legend(handles=legend_elements)
```

[image]